# KineticJS toImage() issue on Android

Tags: kineticjs, todataurl

I'm encountering a problem using KineticJS's toImage() method on some Android devices (including newer devices running android 4+). Weirdly it works fine on others e.g. Kindle Fire HD.

After remote debugging it appears that on Android canvas.toDataURL() method that Kinetic uses is returning 'data:,' as opposed to the usual serialized string returned in desktop browsers.

I've tried the default canvas implementation on these devices and it works fine (e.g. the example at http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/).

I've tried overriding the default toDataURL implementation with a js PNG encoder but it's much too slow for my use case.

Any help much appreciated!